# Shopware 6: association with nested association, is this posible?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, shopware6

I've a association in my EntityDefinition:

```
...
class ParentEntityDefinition extends EntityDefinition
{
    ...
    protected function defineFields(): FieldCollection
    {
        return new FieldCollection([
            
            (new OneToOneAssociationField(
                'childEntity',
                'id',
                'parent_entity_id',
                ChildEntityDefinition::class,
                false)),
        ]);
    }

    ...
}
```

The `ChildEntity` *has a fk_field to currency_entity*. To avoid an additional request to get the currency, **my question**:

- Is, and if, how is it posible to **get the currency entity with nested association?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just use the dot notation to chain associations when you create the `Criteria` programmatically. Given you use the repository of the parent entity:

```php
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->addAssociation('childEntity.currencyEntity');
```

In the request body for an API search request:

```json
{
    "associations": {
        "childEntity": {
            "associations": {
                "currencyEntity": {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes that is totally possible.

You can add nested associations in the following way:

```php
$criteria->addAssociation('childEntity.parentEntity');
```

Note the dot syntax to specify nested associations, the same syntax can be used over the HTTP-API as well.

Take a look at the official docs as well: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/reading-data#associations